# Solving Homogenous First Order ODE Using Substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

### Problem

Find the general solution of the following homogeneous equation.

$$ ty' = y + \sqrt { t^2 - y^2} $$

### Attempt

I'm following the algorithm provided in section 1.5 of the William Adkins & Mark G. Davidson, *Ordinary Differential Equations* textbook on page 63, which suggests rearranging the equation into the form:

$$ y' =  ... $$

where $ y = tv $ and $ y' = v + tv' $ (v is the substitution variable).

I haven't been able to get too far in the procedure to make the substitution:

$$ y' = \frac{y + \sqrt { t^2 - y^2}}{t} $$
$$ y' = \frac{\frac{1}{t}}{\frac{1}{t}} \frac{y + \sqrt { t^2 - y^2}}{t} $$
$$ y' = \frac{y}{t} + \frac{\sqrt { t^2 - y^2}}{t} $$

### Notes

Can someone please help me reduce the RHS of the above equation to the form $ y' = f(\frac{y}{t}) $ (an equation in terms of $ (\frac{y}{t}) $), using the substitution $ y = tv $? For bonus points, please provide a solution to the ODE so myself and other viewers can check their answers!

Thanks in advance!

### Solution

With the help of Isham, I was able to get the solution.

$$ ty' = y + \sqrt { t^2 - y^2 } $$

It is implied that $ t^2 - y^2 \geq 0 $, and so $ t^2 \geq y^2 \gt 0 $ or $ \lt 0 $.

$$ ty' - y = \sqrt { t^2 - y^2} $$
$$ \frac {1}{\sqrt {t^2} } (ty' - y) = \frac {1}{\sqrt {t^2} } \sqrt { t^2 - y^2} $$
$$ \frac {1}{t} (ty' - y) = \sqrt { \frac{t^2}{t^2} - \frac{y^2}{t^2}} $$
$$ y' - \frac{y}{t} = \sqrt { 1 - \frac{y^2}{t^2}} $$
$$ y' - \frac{y}{t} = \sqrt { 1 - (\frac{y}{t})^2} $$
$$ y' = \sqrt { 1 - (\frac{y}{t})^2} + \frac{y}{t} $$

Let $ v = \frac{y}{t} $. Then, $ y = tv $ and so $ y' = \frac{dy}{dt} = v + tv' $. Substituting for $ v $ in the above equation we get:

$$ v + tv' = \sqrt {1 - v^2} + v $$
$$ tv' = \sqrt {1 - v^2} $$

Note, since $ t^2 \geq y^2 $, $ \frac{y^2}{t^2} = v^2 \leq 1 $, so there are no equilibrium cases to consider.

$$ t\frac{dv}{dt} = \sqrt {1 - v^2} $$
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt { 1 - v^2}}dv = \frac{1}{t}dt $$
$$ \int\frac{1}{\sqrt { 1 - v^2}}dv = \int\frac{1}{t}dt $$
$$ arcsin(v) = ln|t| + C_1, C_1 \in \mathbb R $$
$$ \frac {y}{t} = \sin{(ln|t| + C_1)} $$
$$ y = t \sin{(ln|t| + C_1)} $$

Comment: Your substitution is a good approach. After substituting $y$ and $y'$ into your original equation, you would reduce to $$\displaystyle \int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2}}  ~dv = \int \dfrac{1}{t}~dt$$

Comment: +1 you did a good job under "solution"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substitution is fine. 
$$ty' = y + \sqrt { t^2 - y^2}$$
$$ty' - y = \sqrt { t^2 - y^2}$$
$$\frac {ty' - y}{t^2} = \frac 1t \sqrt { 1 - (\frac yt)^2}$$
$$ \left (\frac yt \right )'= \frac 1t \sqrt { 1 - (\frac yt)^2}$$
$$ \int \frac {d\left (\frac yt \right )}{\sqrt { 1 - (\frac yt)^2}}= \int \frac {dt}t $$

Comment: I think I got it! Mind proofreading my answer under "Solution"? I'll then give you credit for the help.

Comment: @AnthonyKrivonos looks correct to me..I see no mistakes. Good job

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: yw @AnthonyKrivonos .....

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: To reduce, you need to ***substitute***  $y=vt$ in RHS and $y'=v+tv'$ in LHS. It would look like this:

$$v+tv'=\frac{tv+t\sqrt{1-v^2}}{t}$$

$$tv'=\sqrt{1-v^2}$$

Where $\displaystyle v'$ is $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}$ Can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

According with the suggested

$$
y'=v+\sqrt{1-v^2}
$$

with

$$
v = \frac yt
$$

so

$$
y' = v + t v'
$$

then

$$
v + t v' = v +\sqrt{1-v^2}
$$

or

$$
\frac{dv}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} = \frac{dt}{t}
$$